# Error with GCP's KMS with gcloud command line: cryptography.hazmat.primitives.keywrap has no aes_key_wrap_with_padding attribute

Tags: ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, dependencies, gcloud

I'm having problems using gcloud command line to import a key into Google KMS, on an Ubuntu instance (php/homestead/vagrant).

I installed gcloud using the following commands:

```
echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https ca-certificates gnupg
curl https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/doc/apt-key.gpg | sudo apt-key --keyring /usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg add -
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install google-cloud-sdk
gcloud init
```

Then I installed the crypto package using these commands:

```
pip install --user "cryptography>=2.2.0"
apt policy python-cryptography`
export CLOUDSDK_PYTHON_SITEPACKAGES=1
```

My php code is eventually running this command through a typical exec call:

```
gcloud kms keys versions import --import-job jobname --location locationname --keyring keyringname --key keyname --algorithm ec-sign-p256-sha256 --public-key-file /tmp/wrapping_public_key.pem --target-key-file /tmp/unwrapped_formatted.key
```

And I always get this error:

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (AttributeError): module 'cryptography.hazmat.primitives.keywrap' has no attribute 'aes_key_wrap_with_padding'
```

It's probably important to note that I can use other functions with gcloud with success, including creation of keyrings, etc. I believe the error is related to how gcloud is installed, or a dependency issue...but I have no idea where to start troubleshooting and the GCP documentation doesn't list this problem specifically.

Any help offered would be *greatly* appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I determined that somehow I had varying versions of cryptography installed using `pip list`, `pip2 list`, and `pip3 list`.

Solved by using the commands below. I'm not quite sure were necessary or not, but I'm up and running with gcloud now.

`pip3 install --upgrade pip` (upgrade pip3)

`pip uninstall cryptography` (and pip2 and pip3)

`sudo apt remove cryptography`

`pip3 install cryptography`